# How to fix an error installing Samba?

Tags: installation, apt, samba

I cannot install Samba in my computer, I get the following error message:

```
Could not connect to 192.168.1.5:3128 (192.168.1.5). - connect (113: No route to host)Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/samba/samba_3.5.11~dfsg-1ubuntu2.3_i386.deb"
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: This sounds like a problem with a proxy server. Do you use a proxy to access the web (or for any other purpose)? What are your proxy settings? `192.168.1.5` is a LAN address, not the actual address of any host on the Internet. Also, is that *all* the text you see when you try to install `samba`? How exactly are you trying to install it?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give the command you used to that got this response. BUT, if you used something like 
sudo apt-get install samba
Possible reasons are: 
Port 3128 is blocked by your firewall or router.

/etc/hosts has an entry for ubuntu.com that is wrong

/etc/apt/sources.list is the package resource list used to locate archives of the package distribution system in use on the system. 
If you have messed around with sources of software, you may have changed this file to NOT USE canonical.com  ( see this page for configuration help [Software Update Configuration](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)
)

Answer (score 0):

You may download .deb file. Just click on your link in the question. After that:

> sudo dpkg -i ./samba_3.5.11~dfsg-1ubuntu2.3_i386.deb